# Adjective meaning "that can be tied"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, adjectives

What is the most common adjective used to describe objects that *can be tied*. I would think of *tieable* but it does not seem to exist in the wiktionary.

Comment: Do you have some reason to think that there *is* a word used to describe objects that can be tied?

Comment: The word you want is certainly *tieable* or *tie-able*.  Elegant Latinate ligations will win you no friends.

Comment: Can you furnish an example of such an object?

Comment: For clarity, can you confirm whether you mean tie as in knot or fasten, as opposed to equal scores?  At least one person seems to see sufficient room for ambiguity.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm not sure that your response is useful.  It's an objection that could be raised to any single word request.  Given the ancient heritage of ropes and knotwork, the huge body of lore surrounding knots and the existence of Knot Theory as a branch of mathematical study, it is not unreasonable to think that somebody might have coined a term for things which may be tied.  English has terms for much more trivial concepts.

Comment: Are you referring to (1) string, rope, etc., the ends of which *can be tied* together in a knot; or (2) to objects around which string, etc. can be tied, e.g. a parcel or box; or (3) things that *can be tied* to each other or something else; e.g. a tree (or person!) being tied to a stake, a gate being tied to a post, a bundle of sticks being tied together; to a tie/draw in a game (as the first answer has assumed)?

Comment: In the absence of further info, I'm voting to close as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: intransitive verb: to be capable of being tied (http://www.yourdictionary.com/tied) -- use *tie(-)* as an adjective or prefix to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

While M-W doesn't include the word, and its not an exact fit, *bindable* means capable of being fastened or secured with a rope or bond.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "The score was tied."  "The (noun) can be tied."  "A tie (noun) is possible." The rules for spelling are not much help, but if the silent "e" were dropped, "tiable" results.  I have seen "tying", but never "tiable".  I have seen "tie-able", but it is an incorrect and meaningless use of the hyphen.  So, use the long form.

Comment: I am willing to bet that Vincent has knots in mind, rather than sporting events.  The choice of "object" rather than "event" implies this, to me at least.  Vincent?

Answer (score 0):

the word [anchorable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anchorable?s=t) springs to mind

Answer (score -1):

You might consider:

> **Pliable**: 1a : supple enough to bend freely or repeatedly without
>   breaking

*from m-w.com*

Comment: @MrDownvote: care to elucidate?